# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable while doing RandomizedSearchCV for logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As a newbie to python cannot figure out why an array object is called in RandomizedSearchCV. Any idea how to resolve/get around this error?

X_train and y_train are numpy ndarrays.

```
tuned_parameters = pd.DataFrame({'C': [10**i for i in range(-4,4,2)]})

#Using RandomizedCV
model =  RandomizedSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), tuned_parameters, 
scoring = 'f1', cv=5, n_jobs=6, random_state = 12)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-9f33fbdbb7e4> in <module>()
      8 #Using RandomizedCV
      9 model =  RandomizedSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), tuned_parameters1,  
n_iter = 10, scoring = 'f1', cv=5, n_jobs=6)
---> 10 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
     11 #model.predict(X_test)
     12 print(model.best_estimator_)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in 
fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    616         n_splits = cv.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)
    617         # Regenerate parameter iterable for each fit
--> 618         candidate_params = list(self._get_param_iterator())
    619         n_candidates = len(candidate_params)
    620         if self.verbose > 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in 
__iter__(self)
    236         # in this case we want to sample without replacement
    237         all_lists = np.all([not hasattr(v, "rvs")
--> 238                             for v in 
self.param_distributions.values()])
    239         rnd = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    240 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not use pandas.**

---

From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html):

> param_distributions : dict Dictionary with parameters names (string)
>   as keys and distributions or lists of parameters to try. Distributions
>   must provide a rvs method for sampling (such as those from
>   scipy.stats.distributions). If a list is given, it is sampled
>   uniformly.

You need to define the `tuned_parameters` differently.

---

**Use this:**

```
tuned_parameters = {"C": [10**i for i in range(-4,4,2)] }
```

Comment: Defining tuned_parameters as dictionary works, Thanks for your answer @seralouk

Comment: perfect. please consider upvoting and accepting my answer